# jQuery empty string select.val()

Tags: jquery, select

Here is my markup

```
 <select id="packages"></select>
```

Here is my JS

```
$.ajax({
    url: "get_packages",
    success: function(data) {
        var form = $("select#packages");
        for (var i=0 ; i<data.length; i++) {
            form.append("<option>"+data[i].package_name+"</option>");
        }
    },
    dataType: "json"
});

var pack = $("#packages").val();
console.log(pack) /* RETURNS UNDEFINED */
```

Here is the model

```
public function get_packages(){
        return $this->db->from("packages")->get()->result_array();
}
```

Controller

```
public function get_packages() {
        header("Content-type: application/json");
        $res = $this->swimsdb->get_packages();

        echo json_encode($res);
}
```

What seems to be the problem here? I have other dropdown boxes but they managed to not return an undefined value. This was the only case where it returned undefined.

Comment: is your jQuery code wrapped in $(document).ready(function(){your code here}); ??

Comment: Here is you can't use words as a variable [JS Reserved](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp)

Comment: @DavidJorHpan I changed the variable name but it still doens't work

Comment: @Sujith my whole script was wrapped inside a $(document).ready(function(){}); yes

Comment: Ensure `$` is jQuery. Executing code `$.fn.jquery` in you browser console window should show jQuery version otherwise it is reference to other library. If that is the issue use `jQuery("#packages").val()`

Answer (score 0):

Add an option to your select element,

```
<select id="packages"><option value=""></option></select>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2rw3ewjL/1/

Comment: still undefined :(

Comment: Without any option `<select id="packages"></select>` it will return `null`. `undefined` is returned when element is not found.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure `$` is jQuery. Executing code `$.fn.jquery` in you browser console window should show jQuery version otherwise it is reference to other library. If that is the issue use `jQuery("#packages").val()`

Answer (score 0):

```
form.append("<option>"+data[i].package_name+"</option>");
```

change above line like this

```
 $form.append("<option>"+data[i].package_name+"</option>");
```

$ for jquery Object